# Validate TRON address using solidity ecrecover

Tags: ethereum, digital-signature, solidity, smartcontracts, tron

I'm trying to validate a signed message using a smart contract running on the TRON network.
I've tried a few different methods but all failed:

Based on [this article](https://medium.com/@angellopozo/ethereum-signing-and-validating-13a2d7cb0ee3) I've deployed the following smart contract:

```
contract Verifier {
    function recoverAddr(bytes32 msgHash, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) returns (address) {
        return ecrecover(msgHash, v, r, s);
    }

    function isSigned(address _addr, bytes32 msgHash, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) returns (bool) {
        return ecrecover(msgHash, v, r, s) == _addr;
    }
}
```

And the following client (js) code:

```
let contract = await tronWeb.contract().at(contract_address);
let msg = tronWeb.sha3('This is my message');
let signature = await tronWeb.trx.sign(msg);

var r = signature.substr(0, 66);
var s = "0x" + signature.substr(66, 64);
var v = "0x" + signature.substr(signature.length - 2);

let hexAddress = await contract.recoverAddr(msg, v, r, s).call();
```

But got back a wrong address.

Based on [this article](https://medium.com/@coredevs/verifying-elliptic-curve-digital-signature-with-tron-smart-contract-5d11347e7b5b) I've deployed the following smart contract:

```
contract Verifier {


  //return the address according to the signature and and the data
  function validate(bytes32 hash, bytes signature)
  public
  pure
  returns (address){
      bytes memory signedString = signature;
      bytes32  r = convertToBytes32(slice(signedString, 0, 32));
      bytes32  s = convertToBytes32(slice(signedString, 32, 32));
      byte  v1 = slice(signedString, 64, 1)[0];
      uint8 v = uint8(v1) + 27;
      return ecrecover(hash, uint8(r), s, bytes32(v));
  }

  //slice function
  function slice(bytes memory data, uint start, uint len)
  private
  pure
  returns (bytes){
      bytes memory b = new bytes(len);
      for(uint i = 0; i < len; i++){
          b[i] = data[i + start];
      }
      return b;
  }
  //convert bytes to bytes32
  function convertToBytes32(bytes memory source)
  private
  pure
  returns (bytes32 result) {
      assembly {
          result := mload(add(source, 32))
      }
  }
}
```

And the following client (js) code:

```
let contract = await tronWeb.contract().at(contract_address);
let msg = tronWeb.sha3('Hello World');
let signature = await tronWeb.trx.sign(msg);
let hexAddress = await contract.validate(msg, signature).call();
```

Still got back a wrong address.

I managed to sign and recover an address using pure js code based on [this](https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/api-advanced.html?highlight=signingkey#id8):

```
const ethers = tronWeb.utils.ethersUtils;
let signingKey = new ethers.SigningKey(tronWeb.defaultPrivateKey);

let message = "This is some message";
let messageBytes = ethers.toUtf8Bytes(message);
let messageDigest = ethers.keccak256(messageBytes);

let signature = signingKey.signDigest(messageDigest);
let recovered = ethers.recoverAddress(messageDigest, signature);
console.log("Recovered address: " + recovered);
```

How can I sign a message using a js code and recover using a smart contract? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.

The smart contract code:

```
contract Verifier {
    function recoverAddr(bytes32 msgHash, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) returns (address) {
        return ecrecover(msgHash, v, r, s);
    }

    function isSigned(address _addr, bytes32 msgHash, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) returns (bool) {
        return ecrecover(msgHash, v, r, s) == _addr;
    }
}
```

The client code:

```
const ethers = tronWeb.utils.ethersUtils;
let contract = await tronWeb.contract().at(contract_address);
let signingKey = new ethers.SigningKey(tronWeb.defaultPrivateKey);

let message = "This is some message";
let messageBytes = ethers.toUtf8Bytes(message);
let messageDigest = ethers.keccak256(messageBytes);

let signature = signingKey.signDigest(messageDigest);
let hexAddress = await contract.recoverAddr(messageDigest, signature.v, signature.r, signature.s).call();
```